# Add a folder with ~20K of images into Google Colaboratory

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I am working with cat breeds recognition with Keras and try to use Google Colaboratory for training on GPU. When I worked in PyCharm, I used a path to folder with images:

```
data_dir = '//home//kate//Рабочий стол//барахло линух минт//more_breeds_all_new'
```

And I can not understand, how can I download a folder with 19500 images to Colab instead loading pictures there one by one like Google offers in it's notebook.
I also have a folder with these images on Google Drive, but I also do not know how to use it as a full folder with it's path.

Comment: Read [tour] and [help/on-topic]. This is not really a programming question, but more of a Google question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: zip image folder in .zip .tar format,example folder_data.zip
and sync or upload it( folder_data.zip) to Google Drive.

Get google drive file_id of zip file( folder_data.zip) like 1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE_vIKouTKyIDjEq

Second:
I recommend you use Pydrive to download your file from google drive to colab notebook VM . I download 500MB dataset for 5s.
1. install Pydrive

```
!pip install PyDrive
```

2. OAouth

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once in a notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

3. code for download file from google drive

   `fileId = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'DRIVE_FILE_ID'}) #DRIVE_FILE_ID is file id example: 1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE_vIKouTKyIDjEq
   print fileId['title']  # folder_data.zip
   fileId.GetContentFile('folder_data.zip')  # Save Drive file as a local file`

Finaly: unzip it to folder, example in here is

```
!unzip folder_data.zip -d ./
```

list file look like it

```
folder_data.zip
folder_data/
```

Cheer Mo Jihad