# Google Colab is very slow compared to my PC

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've recently started to use Google Colab, and wanted to train my first Convolutional NN. I imported the images from my Google Drive thanks to the answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351071/load-image-dataset-folder-or-zip-located-in-google-drive-to-google-colab).

Then I pasted my code to create the CNN into Colab and started the process.
Here is the complete code:

### Part 1: Setting up Colab to import picture from my Drive

(part 1 is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351071/load-image-dataset-folder-or-zip-located-in-google-drive-to-google-colab) as it worked as exptected for me

Step 1:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
```

Step 2:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Step 3:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

Step 4:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Step 5:

```
print('Files in Drive:')
!ls drive/
```

### Part 2: Copy pasting my CNN

I created this CNN with tutorials from a Udemy Course. It uses keras with tensorflow as backend.
For the sake of simplicity I uploaded a really simple version, which is plenty enough to show my problems

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

parameters

```
imageSize=32

batchSize=64

epochAmount=50
```

CNN

```
classifier=Sequential() 

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (imageSize, imageSize, 3), activation = 'relu')) #convolutional layer

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))) #pooling layer

classifier.add(Flatten())
```

ANN

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu')) #hidden layer

classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) #output layer

classifier.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy']) #training method
```

image preprocessing

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) 

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('drive/School/sem-2-2018/BSP2/UdemyCourse/CNN/dataset/training_set',
                                             target_size = (imageSize, imageSize),
                                             batch_size = batchSize,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('drive/School/sem-2-2018/BSP2/UdemyCourse/CNN/dataset/test_set',
                                        target_size = (imageSize, imageSize),
                                        batch_size = batchSize,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = (8000//batchSize),
                     epochs = epochAmount,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = (2000//batchSize))
```

### Now comes my Problem

First of, the training set I used is a database with 10000 dog and cat pictures of various resolutions. (8000 training_set, 2000 test_set)

I ran this CNN on Google Colab (with GPU support enabled) and on my PC (tensorflow-gpu on GTX 1060)

This is an intermediate result from my PC:

```
Epoch 2/50
63/125 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6382 - acc: 0.6520
```

And this from Colab:

```
Epoch 1/50
13/125 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:00:51 - loss: 0.7265 - acc: 0.4916
```

Why is Google Colab so slow in my case?

Personally I suspect a bottleneck consisting of pulling and then reading the images from my Drive, but I don't know how to solve this other than choosing a different method to import the database.

Comment: Yeah, I also think this is happening because of networking overhead because of accessing data from drive. You can try to copy your data from drive to  colab instance, so that it's available locally.

Comment: @charel-f I have the same problem with colab, did you find a solution? Would you mind sharing a colab-notebook for the people reading your question?

Comment: I am asking too for your answer if you figured it out.

Comment: Sorry @NeStack, I did not really work with colab recently and I found no better answer than those linked below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @[Feng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588431/feng) has already noted, reading files from drive is very slow. [This](https://medium.com/@oribarel/getting-the-most-out-of-your-google-colab-2b0585f82403) tutorial suggests using some sort of a memory mapped file like hdf5 or lmdb in order to overcome this issue. This way the I\O Operations are much faster (for a complete explanation on the speed gain of hdf5 format see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710245/is-there-an-analysis-speed-or-memory-usage-advantage-to-using-hdf5-for-large-arr)).

Comment: While I am not working with Google Colab anymore, I have to disagree. While this answer is maybe not in correct StackOverflow style, it at least provides future interested readers some material/tutorial they can follow to maybe get an answer. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 26):

It's very slow to read file from google drives.

For example, I have one big file(39GB).

It cost more than 10min when I exec '!cp drive/big.file /content/'.

After I shared my file, and got the url from google drive. It cost 5 min when I exec '! wget -c -O big.file http://share.url.from.drive'. Download speed can up to 130MB/s.

Comment: What is the max local space allowed on the colab instance?

Comment: @Kannaiyan You can check the available space using `!df -h`

Comment: Yep, this gives 50-500x times faster result in my case, training with images.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue. Here's how I solved it:-

1. Uploaded the zip file of the dataset to google drive.
2. Mount the drive in colab and then unzip the dataset file 'in' a separate folder(other than ../drive) in colab itself.
3. Do your business.

It worked for me. I don't know the exact reason but since colab access its local directory faster than it accesses the mounted drive directory, that may happen to be the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and here's how I solved it.

First, make sure GPU is enabled(because it is not by default) by going to Runtime -> Change runtime type, and choosing GPU as your Hardware accelerator.

Then, as shown [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb#scrollTo=Ti8avTlLofoJ) you can use cache() and prefetch() functions to optimize the performance. Example:

```
# Load dataset
train_ds = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('Data/train',labels="inferred")
val_ds = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('Data/test',labels="inferred")

# Standardize data (optional)
from tensorflow.keras import layers
normalization_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))

# Cache to RAM (optional)
from tensorflow import data
AUTOTUNE = data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# Train
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=3)
```

Comment: In my case (also training a CNN fecthing images from Google Drive) the prefetch to RAM code suggested here improved the situation. Without it, the first epoch took almost 10 minutes to complete (the following ones 10-12 seconds each, probably because images where cached in RAM by that time). With the addition of the prefetch calls the first epoch execution time halved (the following ones remained the same).

Answer (score 5):

Reading files from google drive slow down your training process. The solution is to upload zip file to colab and unzip there. Hope it is clear for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can load your data as numpy array (.npy format) and use flow method instead of flow_from_directory. Colab provides 25GB RAM ,so even for big data-sets you can load your entire data into memory. The speed up was found to be aroud 2.5x, with the same data generation steps!!!
(Even faster than data stored in colab local disk i.e '/content' or google drive.

Since colab provides only a single core CPU (2 threads per core), there seems to be a bottleneck with CPU-GPU data transfer (say K80 or T4 GPU), especially if you use data generator for heavy preprocessing or data augmentation.
You can also try setting different values for parameters like 'workers', 'use_multiprocessing', 'max_queue_size ' in fit_generator method ...

Comment: Colab also provides dual core CPU...                                                                        Also checkout : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8485684

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on datasets from kaggle check [this](https://medium.com/@saedhussain/google-colaboratory-and-kaggle-datasets-b57a83eb6ef8#:%7E:text=Step%203%3A%20Upload%20Kaggle%20API%20json%20file%20to%20Google%20Colab&text=PS%3A%20You%20could%20use%20this,the%20files%20in%20the%20directory.)

**Remember :** Inside Google colab Linux commands are ran by prefixing **'!'**

**eg :**

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

```
!ls !unzip -q downloaded_file.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the GPU on colab is super fast compared to my Nvidia GPU card on PC- based on training speeds. However, when doing simulations, which I can only presume involves CPU, my PC is nearly 50% faster (i7, 10th Gen)

Answer (score -2):

Google Colab instances are using some faster memory than google drive. As you are accessing files from google drive (it has a larger access time) so you are getting low speed. First copy the files to colab instance then train your network.

Answer (score -5):

I have the same question as to why the GPU on colab seems to be taking at least just as long as my local pc so I can't really be of help there. But with that being said, if you are trying to use your data locally, I have found the following process to be significantly faster than just using the upload function provided in colab.

1.) mount google drive

```
# Run this cell to mount your Google Drive.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2.) create a folder outside of the google drive folder that you want your data to be stored in

3.) use the following command to copy the contents from your desired folder in google drive to the folder you created

```
  !ln -s "/content/drive/My Drive/path_to_folder_desired" "/path/to/the_folder/you created"
```

(this is referenced from [another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338621/issue-with-gdrive-on-colab) response that I used to find a solution to a similar issue )

4.) Now you have your data available to you at the path, "/path/to/the_folder/you created"

Comment: This answer is wrong. `ln -s` does not copy anything, it creates a symlink, and all data under the new path will be still accessed from the Google Drive.