# Keras running on GCloud ML Engine with GPU is slower than locally with CPU

Tags: keras, gpu, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I have a Mobilenet build on Keras. Running it locally takes around 290 seconds every step, but when I run on the GCLoud ML Engine it takes over 400 seconds.I put the following line on my code:

```
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

And the log is the following:

```
['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0']
```

I have also tried to change from 1 GPU to 4 GPU but the result is the same.  Do I have to change any code to optimize Keras on GPU?

Comment: This can happen if your batch size is not large enough, I have explained the same in this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295934/best-way-to-import-data-in-google-colaboratory-for-fast-computing-and-training/54453951#54453951

Comment: Thanks for the response @anand_v.singh , but that does not seem to be the solution. I have increased the batch size and the execution time does not change.

Comment: IO could be the bottleneck. What's your data format and how do you read them?

Comment: My data are images of 224x224 and are read with this function https://github.com/slequeux/xke-cloudml/blob/master/cloud_train/trainer/keras_gs.py

Comment: Which GPUs are you using locally and on ML Engine? Please reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com if you continue to experience issues training your models.